# How can i transfer table data from SandBox to production in a outbound change set?

Tags: salesforce

I have a sandbox instance  and I create a outbound change set which include triggers, classes and custom objects. I select the dependencies and they are added to the outbound changeset .
Now there is a custom object that I have in Sandbox , Test_Master and it will create a custom object Test_Master__c , it is a tracking for real time triggers. It has rows in the table in Sandbox.
Now when i deploy to Production the table is deployed  but the rows in the table are not .

Is there a way to deploy both schema and data in the table ?

Answer (score 0):

No, deployments push "metadata" - custom objects, fields, classes, worflows etc. They don't push data.

You need Data Loader, in-browser import wizard, `sfdx` if you're comfortable with commandline... Or integration tools like Informatica, Azure Data Factory.

If it's one-off check if the import wizard works for you. It's accessible on the object's tab (assuming you have one), "Import" button. Or in setup's search start typing "import". Export from sandbox... Again, data loader? Maybe a report exported as CSV?